# How to mention path in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file which extracts the Filename and modified time of all zip file from the folder and saves it into .csv file.

Is there any way that I can add the path of folder in source code itself?
So, if the .bat file is on desktop,then also it would get all the files names from the mentioned folder path and would create a .csv file on desktop itself?

```
>"File_names.csv" ( for /r %%a in (*.zip) do @echo %%~ta,"%%~nxa" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup this is possible! You can clarify the path as one argument of the for-loop like this:

```
>"File_names.csv" (for /r "C:\Path To\MyZipFiles\" %%a in (*.zip) do @echo %%~ta, %%~nxa )
```

Comment: I am getting file name inside "Filename".Could you please eliminate " "??

Comment: I don't quite understand, what you mean... I have multiple double quotes and copied most of the code from your question! Only thing that changed was the addition of the path.

Comment: the file name in .csv file has double quotes attached to it at the start and the end.This wasn't appearing previously.

Comment: Done.... Though this should have appeared previously as well according to the code you have provided in the question...